# adding toplevel json namespace (or model name) in extractArray

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember app with a Product model. My server response is json like this (for one entry)

```
{
   "id": "a01dfaa0",
   "type": "computer",
   "cost": "0.50"
}
```

or an array of such objects

```
   [{
       "id": "6b2360d0",
       "type": "fridge",
       "cost": "2.50"
   },{
       "id": "a01dfaa1",
       "type": "car",
       "cost": "5.95"
   }]
```

In other words, there is no top level namespace (based on the model name), which Ember expects. When I return the data to the Ember app, I know I can run it through the extractArray function to add that namespace (either "product" or "products" I'm assuming) but I can't figure out how to do  it. Question: how would I do that

```
extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {

}
```

Update, if I use the method proposed by the first answer, namely put this in my DS.RESTSerializer

```
// Override
extractArray(store, type, payload) {
  payload = this._extractPayload(Ember.String.pluralize(type.typeKey), payload);
  return this._super(store, type, payload);
},

// Override    
extractSingle(store, type, payload, id) {
  payload = this._extractPayload(type.typeKey, payload);
  return this._super(store, type, payload, id);
},

_extractPayload(typeKey, payload) {
  var conformPayload = {};
  if (payload) {
    conformPayload[typeKey] = payload;
  }
  return conformPayload;
}
```

I get an error when my server responds with an empty array. Ember normally expects this `{products : [] }` when there are no records, so I'm returning `[]` when there are no records, but with the above extractArray method, it throws an error, saying the `response from findAll must be an array, not undefined Error`. When I do `console.log(payload)` in the extractArray function it shows an empty array `[]`. Question, how do I modify Ember in the RESTSerializer so that it can work with json without the toplevel namespace, and, if it's not supposed to receive an empty array `[]` when there are no records in the db, then what is it supposed to receive?

Note, since the server expects the json without the toplevel namespace, I  I send it to the server through the serializeIntoHash function of the RestAdapter to remove the  namespace (the typekey) from the json (but I can't figure out how to add it back in the extractArray function)

```
  serializeIntoHash: function( hash, type, record, options ) {
    console.log(hash, type, record, options, "h,t,r,o");
    // Usergrid does not expect a type-key
    record.eachAttribute(function( name, meta ) {
      hash[name] = record.get(name);
    });

    return hash;
  }
```

Update
this is the stacktrace of the error I'm getting when I run any of the suggested answers

```
Error while processing route: gopher Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined Error: Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:22707:21)
    at Object.Ember.default.assert (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:15408:13)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:64040:17
    at Object.Backburner.run (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:10778:27)
    at ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend._adapterRun (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:70295:33)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:64037:15
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:55993:16)
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:56005:17)
    at publish (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:55976:11)
```

Update. This is the full adapter and serializer code (I'm not using Ember-Cli)

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({


});
// Must extend REST serializer to handle Usergrid JSON format, which is 
// different from what Ember-Data expects.
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

  extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id) {
  var convertedPayload = {};
  convertedPayload[type.modelName] = payload;
  return this._super(store, type, convertedPayload, id);
},

extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
  console.log(payload, "payload");
  var convertedPayload = {};
  convertedPayload[type.modelName] = payload;
  return this._super(store, type, convertedPayload);
},


});
```

Comment: The title of your question presupposes a particular solution. It would be more general if stated as something like "Ember Data: how to deal with payloads from server missing root key".

Comment: Just tried your code and it works for me... Are you overriding the `normalizePayload` function? And which version of Ember are you using exactly? Furthermore what is in `convertedPayload` before you pass it to `this._super` in `extractArray`? You can also try to debug into that function to see when the payload goes "undefined"...

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/4f0176fa0d3caed29389a462c4a244ef673ffea0/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest-serializer.js#L574 this is the function where the `primaryArray` goes undefined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.18 and up (using `modelName`)

```
serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, snapshot, options) {
  Ember.merge(hash, this.serialize(snapshot, options));
},

extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id) {
  var convertedPayload = {};
  convertedPayload[type.modelName] = payload;
  return this._super(store, type, convertedPayload, id);
},

extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
  var convertedPayload = {};
  convertedPayload[type.modelName] = payload;
  return this._super(store, type, convertedPayload);
}
```

Here is a working JSBin that demonstrates this: http://jsbin.com/bebori/1/edit?js,output

### Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.17 and lower (using `typeKey`)

```
serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, snapshot, options) {
  Ember.merge(hash, this.serialize(snapshot, options));
},

extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id) {
  var convertedPayload = {};
  convertedPayload[type.typeKey] = payload;
  return this._super(store, type, convertedPayload, id);
},

extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
  var convertedPayload = {};
  convertedPayload[type.typeKe] = payload;
  return this._super(store, type, convertedPayload);
}
```

Here is a working JSBin that demonstrates this: http://jsbin.com/hanuwa/1/edit?js,output

I believe the problem with the other answer that looks quite similar to this one is the use of `Ember.String.pluralize` - I don't think that should be there.

Comment: I tried your solution and got the same error: `Error whiel processing route: product Assertion Failed. The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined Error:` When I check network traffic in Chrome console, I see that the response from my get request is `[]`, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the stack trace in the console

Comment: I updated the OP with the stacktrace. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please also provide your full adapter and serializer code.. The whole file (including `import Ember from 'ember';` at the top)

Comment: ok, I updated the OP. I'm not using Ember-Cli (as you'll be able to tell) so no `import Ember from 'ember'` statements etc

Comment: Leahcim - I've updated my answer with working JSBin examples. I've also done a third JSBin (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tilevo/2/edit?html,js,output) where I copy/paste your `ApplicationAdapter` and `ApplicationSerializer` directly. While creating this I did run into the same problem you did `Error: Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined` - this happened because I created a JSBin that used `modelName` but the Ember Data version was before 1.0.0-beta.18 - so `modelName` didn't exist - are you using Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.18 or an earlier version?

Comment: I'm using Ember 1.12.0, and Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.17 (I think it's supposed to be modelName starting in 1.0.0-beta.17), and jquery 1.11.3 http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/21/ember-data-1-0-beta-18-released.html

Comment: `modelName` is only available in beta.18 not beta.17. If you're using beta.17 change the code to `typeKey`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the typeKey to create an ember data conform payload like this:

Use type.modelName instead of type.typeKey in ember data beta 18 (http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/21/ember-data-1-0-beta-18-released.html)

```
// Override
extractArray(store, type, payload) {
  payload = this._extractPayload(Ember.String.pluralize(type.typeKey), payload);
  return this._super(store, type, payload);
},

// Override    
extractSingle(store, type, payload, id) {
  payload = this._extractPayload(type.typeKey, payload);
  return this._super(store, type, payload, id);
},

_extractPayload(typeKey, payload) {
  var conformPayload = {};
  if (payload) {
    conformPayload[typeKey] = payload;
  }
  return conformPayload;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've only tried the extractArray function so far, but it throws an error 'product typeKey is not defined '. Note, right now on application load my server is returning an empty array (since it has no records but that shouldn't make a difference, and I need it to work even when there are no records in the db). Do you know why this error is happening?

Comment: If you're using the latest ember data version (v1.0.0-beta.17/18), then you have to use modelName instead of typeKey. Oh and of course, for empty arrays it wouldnt work, I will edit the code above :)

Comment: You're right I need to use type.modelName, but what do I need to do when there are no records in my db? Should I not return an empty array and, if not, what instead? If I need to return an empty array, how do I handle it? The reason I returned an empty array is because ember requires one if I do have a top level namespace, for example {products : [] }  works , but if I remove the namespace, shouldn't I then just return an empty array from  the server, like this [ ]

Comment: Also, aren't these functions? Shouldn't it be extractArray: function(store, type, payload){... etc?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Yes those are functions, just written in ES6 syntax. For empty data, ember-data expects { products: [] } for arrays and { product: {} } for a single resource. You could either try to return 204 No Content status code or just return "[]" for arrays and "{}" for objects, since the deserialization above will marshal it to { products: [] }, etc.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest defining your own `find` on the adapter. It would do an ajax call and push the payload into the store. See http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_find.

The below uses `fetch` (replace with `$.ajax` if you prefer).

```
// adapters/product.js
...
find(store, type, id, snapshot) {
  function get()          { return fetch(url); }
  function json(response) { return response.json(); }
  function push(json)     { return store.pushPayload({ products: json }); }

  var url = this.buildURL ('product', id);
  return get() . then(json) . then(push);
}
```

Using `this.buildURL` ensures that the URL is build correctly, including the namespace, pluralization, etc.

Overriding `extractArray` and its friends is not too much fun and is bug-prone. I'd reserve that approach for trickier cases.

For going back up to the server, using `serializeIntoHash` is fine, but the following would be bit more compact and robust:

```
// app/serializers/product.js
serializeIntoHash: function(data, type, record, options) {
  Ember.merge(data, this.serialize(record, options));
}
```

Comment: I also tried your solution and got the same error as with the others: Error whiel processing route: product Assertion Failed. The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined Error: When I check network traffic in Chrome console, however, I see that the response from my server is [] (i.e. an Array), so I'm not sure what the problem is. Any idea?

Comment: This was just sample code. If you want `findAll` to work, you'll have to implement it in a similar way. Meanwhile, you could check that the above works correctly for the simple case of `this.store.find('product', id)`.

Comment: I did use the find code in findAll and got the same error. the database is empty. I'm not sure how to get a sample entry in it in the required format to run `this.store.find('product', id)` however, since your solution is throwing the exact same error as the two other suggested solutions...I updated the OP with the stacktrace of the error if you're interested. Thank you for the help you did provide.